# How to compare two .csv and .xlsx files and print out mismatched for a particular field?

Tags: python, excel, csv

So it doesn't matter if they are two different .csv or .xlsx files. 
But I need a common way on how to tell the mismatched fields. 
Both Files are different in terms of both shape and size.

For example file A might have 32,000 rows but file B might only have 16,000.
This is because I am trying to compare the drift across two different databases from a report. 
One of the databases is a source for the other. 
For example: dbA feeds into dbB, making dbA a superset to dbB.

The problem now arises, that I am trying to match employeeID in both databases.

For example, let's say file A contains the following

```
firstname, lastname, namekey, employeeID, SSN
```

file B contains

```
firstname, lastname, namekey, username, email_address, phone_number, EmployeeID, SSN
```

The Field I have to match would be based on employeeID=EmployeeID. 
How can I print out a diff view that would only show the rows, where ID did not match?

- I don't want rows from file A that are not in file B
- I don't want rows from file B that are not in file A
- I just want rows where the employee ID is mismatched based on some criteria from both files

The criteria could be anything, technically I can run a SQL command to pull out the .csv or .xlsx file to pull out some key-unique identifier as we have common names but a different employee ID number.

So I guess SSN could be the main filter to say hey, this ID is different for this SSN. 
I just need a way to accomplish this and generate a single file that shows the difference. I could care less what language I have to use as I am familiar with a lot of different things. But mainly Python or some other tool that would be good at parsing this and is not OS-dependent.

I have tried this, thus far:

```
vimdiff
git diff --color-words="[^[:space:],]+" x.csv y.csv
```

Both of them showcase it well, but I don't want rows that are not in both files to appear in the output. Otherwise, it just creates a lot of noise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To read all values in a column from a csv:

```
from csv import DictReader as csv_DictReader
csv_file = defaultdict(list)
filepath = "whatever/myfile.csv"
with filepath.open(encoding="cp1252") as file:
    reader = csv_DictReader(file)  
    for row in reader:
        for (k, v) in row.items():
            csv_file[k].append(v)
csv_column = csv_file['employeeID']  # Tell it what column to read
```

To read all values in a column from excel:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
filepath = "whatever/myfile.xlsx"
excel_file = load_workbook(filepath)
excel_sheet = excel_file.active
excel_columns = {}
for column in "ABC": # Tell it what columns to read
    if column not in excel_columns:
        excel_columns[column] = []
    for row in range(1, excel_sheet.max_row + 1):
        cell_name = f"{column}{row}"
        recovered_columns[column].append(self.excel_sheet[cell_name].value)
```

So we've read the entire files, but now you have just two dicts, one is `csv_column` and the other one is `excel_columns`.

All you have to do now is just to compare the results.

**Suggestion:** print both `csv_column` and `excel_columns` to check what you got using those codes above (because let's be fully honest here, those I just copypasted them from a project that I was working on last year but I forgot half of it already so I'm not entirely sure of the output. It just works).

Comment: Will this compare two .csv or .xlsx files, I only see one file instantiated within the code as `excel_file` and `csv_file`. I really need to compare one column from two files that I pull from two databases and print out the inconsistencies if and only if `employeeID` is mismatched.

Comment: I also found this, but it still leaves rows in there from file A and from file B, whereas I really just need something like a drift report and just output the mismatched pieces of data in a merged file.

Comment: By the way, I greatly appreciate your help and insight @Saelyth.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response, I went to sleep. So... those codes are merely the "how to read columns from excel" and "how to read columns from .csv". It's just a try at pointing you to the right direction, but it's not complete. You need to tinker the code to read only the columns that you need. And you also need to figure out how to compare the results. I suggest you use a loop for that. I'm sorry that I can't help more on this topic.

Comment: It's not a problem I have something that might be able to help compare, the only problem is that it adds all the rows together in a concatenated file...so really the two file are merged and it highlights the differences.